# Como rodar uma aplicação PHP no IIS?

Tags: php, iis

Eu tenho um website em PHP que quero instalar no IIS (Apache para Windows não é uma opção).

Ele não irá rodar naturalmente como uma aplicação .NET.
Por isso, eu já baixei uma release do PHP no site http://windows.php.net, mas ainda tenho que configurar o IIS para interpretar a aplicação em PHP usando essas dll's.

Como faço isso?

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste artigo, acredito que vai te ajudar. http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh994589.aspx }

Comment: > Só uma sugestão, o **PHP** no **IIS** não roda tão rápido quanto no Apache2, então não espere que sua aplicação fique performática.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Esse é o jeito mais difícil.

Experimente seguir os seguintes passos usando o Windows Platform Installer: http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

1. Na parte superior da janela *Web Platform Installer*, clique em **Produtos**.
2. Clique em **Estruturas** e selecione a versão atual do PHP. (Na data desta resposta, a versão atual é PHP 5.3.13.)
3. Clique em **Instalar**.
4. A página Instalação do Web Platform exibe a versão do PHP e suas dependências que serão instaladas.
5. Clique em **Aceito**.
6. O Web PI instala os pacotes do PHP.
7. Clique em **Concluir**.

Comment: Nota: Rodar PHP no IIS funciona até que bem, mas algumas funcionalidades e .htaccess podem não funcionar.

Comment: @OlimonF. , obviamente... htaccess é do Apache, nada a ver com IIS ou PHP. O equivalente é o web.config: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Answer (score 4):

A versão para rodar com IIS do php será NTS. Baixe aqui: http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-7.1.5-nts-Win32-VC14-x86.zip. - Link atualizado para a versão mais recente do dia 07/06/2017

Após download, descompacte e modifique essas linhas dentro do php.ini:

```
;cgi.force_redirect = 1
;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
;fastcgi.impersonate = 1
```

Retire o ; do início e modifique a diretiva cgi.force_redirect para 0. Vai ficar assim:

```
cgi.force_redirect = 0
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
fastcgi.impersonate = 1
```

Abra o menu executar (tecla do windows + R) e digite *appwiz.cpl* e vá em *Ativar ou desativar recursos do windows*, procure *Serviços de informações de internet -> Serviços da world wide web -> Recursos de desenvolvimento de aplicativos*, marque a opção *CGI* para o IIS poder processar aplicações CGI e FASTCGI. Após isso, vá novamente no menu executar e digite *inetmgr* para abrir o gerenciador do IIS. Dentro do gerenciador procurar *Mapeamentos de Manipulador*, clicar duas vezes com botão esquerdo e no canto direito *Adicionar Mapeamento de Módulos*. Abrirá uma tela igual da imagem abaixo, alterar e dar OK. IIS já está pronto para processar páginas em php.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Volte a página anterior, vá em *Documento padrão* e no canto direito *Adicionar* adicione index.php.

Comment: A parte do _Documento padrão_ pra mim não tem jeito de funcionar... Alguma ideia? Se eu tento acessar uma pasta, retorna "No input file specified."... PS: também tentei editar as Restrições da Solicitação para aceitar "Arquivo ou Pasta".

Comment: Em restrições da solicitação deixe arquivo! reinicie o IIS e veja se muda alguma coisa, ou então reinicie o computador!!!!